# Why is `useEffect` not re-running when the dependencies change?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Background:
I was trying to fetch all the links for a set of images, then fetch the real assets for images using the links fetched.

```
let imageLinks = [];

useEffect(() => {
    fetch("http://localhost:3001/video/1?offset=0&count=100")
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((res) => {
            imageLinks = res.frames;
        });
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
    Promise.all(
        imageLinks.map((link) =>
            fetch("http://localhost:3001/" + link).then((res) => res.json())
        )
    ).then((res) => console.log(res));

// update when the image links changed
}, [imageLinks]);
```

The last `useEffect` didn't seem to be working, even when `imageLinks` has been updated in the previous `useEffect`. Could anyone please tell me why is that?

Comment: Something needs to trigger an update for the component.

Answer (score 4):

In your example, `imageLinks` is just a variable inside the React component. If the component's prop or state was to change, the variable's value would be reset to [] on each re-render.

To keep React in sync with `imageLinks` current value, you would need to save it in state. To do this, you need to use `useState`.

In the example below, when `setImageLinks` is called it will get stored in React's state, the component will re-render and it will be passed to the effect. The effect will then check if `imageLinks` has changed and run the effect, if so:

```js
const [imageLinks, setImageLinks] = React.useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    fetch("http://localhost:3001/video/1?offset=0&count=100")
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((res) => {
            setImageLinks(res.frames);
        });
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
    Promise.all(
        imageLinks.map((link) =>
            fetch("http://localhost:3001/" + link).then((res) => res.json())
        )
    ).then((res) => console.log(res));

// update when the image links changed
}, [imageLinks]);
```

Further to this, it may simplify your code if you group your fetches together rather than having them as separate effects.